# Rails "no route matches"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I feel like I'm missing something really simple here...

I have a few files meant to be downloaded from the public folder in my application. To handle it properly I did a class like this:

```
class UpdatesController < ApplicationController
  def download teste
    if params[:filename]
      file_path = "#{Rails.public_path}/download/#{params[:filename]}"
      send_file file_path, :filename => "#{params[:filename]}", :disposition => 'attachment'
    end
  end
end
```

Now, my routes.rb looks like:

```
match "updates/download/:filename" => "updates#download", :as => :getupdate
```

And I link the file like so:

```
<%= link_to "Download this thing", getupdate_url(:filename => entry.file_name) , :class => "btn btn-mini" %>
```

Well, the url is generated correctly, I am redirected to the right address:

```
http://localhost:3000/updates/download/test.zip
```

And I get the following message:

```
No route matches [GET] "/updates/download/test.zip"
```

In my console I typed `rake routes` and I got this:

```
$ rake routes
getupdate        /updates/download/:filename(.:format) updates#download
```

The file is in the following path:

```
.../myapp/public/download/test.zip
```

What's wrong here!?

Comment: can you please try `http://localhost:3000/updates/download/test` instead of `http://localhost:3000/updates/download/test.zip`...and let me know...Thanks

Comment: Thanks man! That's the issue! So simple yet I didn't see it coming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you please try `http://localhost:3000/updates/download/test` instead of `http://localhost:3000/updates/download/test.zip`...and let me know...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to `Rajarshi Das`!

The error occurs because of the dot!

I changed the routes.rb to do this instead:

```
match "updates/download(/:filename)" => "updates#download", :as => :getupdate, :constraints => { :filename => /[^\/]+/ }
```

I really appreciate! I spent a lot of time in this!

Comment: you should mark his answer as correct if he helped you solve your question

Comment: When I got the answer it was only a comment. I already marked the correct answer. Can you please remove the down vote?